# Dante SOCKS5 proxy server configuration for ipv6

Tags: socks, dante

Below is my dante configuration file

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: enp0s3 port = 1080
external: enp0s3
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

It works in ipv4 when ipv6 disabled, this how I disabled ipv6

```
vim /etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.enp0s3.disable_ipv6 = 1

sysctl -p
```

But when ipv6 is enabled, its not returning expected result

---

This is how I test the connection

```
curl -x socks5://user:pass@192.168.1.11:1080 ifconfig.co
```

---

Result

```
curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 2606:4700:3036::ac43:85e4:80. (6)
```